# Is there a way to terminate a two conductor cable to a BNC plug?

Tags: connector, cables, bnc

I have a device with a two conductor cable that I need to interface to a signal conditioner with a BNC input (same as that on a standard oscilloscope). I would rather not use a hacky solution like a screw terminal to BNC adapter and directly terminate the cable with a male BNC plug.

Comment: BNC is designed for COAX cables which are two conductor (one of which is grounded). If your "two conductor" output isn't designed for a COAX cable/connection then I see no other solution than a "hacked" solution. Beware that the BNC input's shield is likely to be grounded, your device needs to be able to handle that. If not you might need **two** BNC inputs.

Comment: One of the conductors carries a signal ground if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I now think I get a better understanding of what you need.
A few vendors offer a pre-wired BNC which is mainly used as test leads.
[Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/pomona-electronics/4969/501-1030-ND/603340) has something like it, but a simple "2 wire to bnc" google search will return a few hits.

Comment: Not quite, I have a non COAX cable with two internal conductors that I want to put a bnc plug on the end of.

Comment: @DarrenMc I've updated my answer to reflect your clarification

Comment: I don't see why you should even keep the "old answer" part since it's just wrong and will confuse anyone looking for the solution to the problem. Stack Exchange has a built-in edit history for those who are curious.